# Prove this function is injective and determine its image

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Fix three distinct primes p, q, r,
prove that the map

$Z_{pqr} → Z_{pq} × Z_{qr} × Z_{pr}$ by $[x]_{pqr}$ → ($[x]_{pq}$, $[x]_{qr}$, $[x]_{pr}$)

is injective and determine its image.

My attempt:

To prove it is injective, I said let there be $x$ and $y$ such that $[x]_{pq}=[y]_{pq}$. This means $pq|(x-y)$
So, one of $p$ or $q$ must divide $(x-y)$.
Similarly, either $p$ or $r$ and either $q$ or $r$ must divide $x-y$ as well. Therefore, one of p,q,r must divide $x-y$.

This implies $pqr|(x-y)$,
So, $[x]_{pqr}=[y]_{pqr}$
This proves that the function is injective (if I'm correct in my implications).

Now, how do I determine its image?

Comment: From the fact that one of $p,q,r$ divide $x-y$ you can't conclude $pqr$ divide $x-y$

Answer (score 1):

$pq \mid x-y$, so we have $p \mid x-y$ AND $q\mid x-y$

$qr \mid x-y$, so ALSO $r\mid x-y$

As $p$, $q$ AND $r$ divide $x-y$ and are distinct primes, we have $pqr \mid x-y$